# Install Magento 2.3 without multisource inventory

Tags: magento2.3, multi-source-inventory

How can I install Magento 2.3 without the multisource inventory modules?
Do I have to require each core module instead of magento/product by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some particular reason why do you want to install Magento 2.3 without MSI? Because MSI it's not just Multi-Sourcing, but it's a brand new Inventory mechanism which in 2.4 will fully substitute CatalogInventory, which is already deprecated since 2.3.0

Comment: Ah okay I was just scared by the many modules. Then everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

There are 41 modules in `module-inventory` namespace. You can try to disable all these modules using CLI command:

```
$./bin/magento module:disable --clear-static-content \
    Magento_Inventory \
    Magento_InventoryAdminUi \
    Magento_InventoryApi \
    Magento_InventoryBundleProduct \
    Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi \
    Magento_InventoryCache \
    Magento_InventoryCatalog \
    Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi \
    Magento_InventoryCatalogApi \
    Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch \
    Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct \
    Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi \
    Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer \
    Magento_InventoryConfiguration \
    Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi \
    Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection \
    Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi \
    Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi \
    Magento_InventoryElasticsearch \
    Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct \
    Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi \
    Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer \
    Magento_InventoryImportExport \
    Magento_InventoryIndexer \
    Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification \
    Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi \
    Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi \
    Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi \
    Magento_InventoryProductAlert \
    Magento_InventoryReservations \
    Magento_InventoryReservationsApi \
    Magento_InventorySales \
    Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi \
    Magento_InventorySalesApi \
    Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi \
    Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator \
    Magento_InventoryShipping \
    Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi \
    Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi \
    Magento_InventorySourceSelection \
    Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
```

Comment: I already accepted the fact, that the MSI inventory will replace all of the inventory ... My question was also more about not installing those modules at all. Thanks anyways :-)